# How to install PHP SOAP on REDHAT 5

Tags: php, linux, soap, redhat

How can I install SOAP php extension on REDHAT 5 server which runs PHP 4.4.5

I was not able to use yum since the os is not registered(and I have no rights to register)

I havent find any compatible versions of SOAP for PHP 4.4.5

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native SOAP extension is only available since PHP 5.0.1. Because your server is running PHP4, you'll have to use a third party SOAP framework, such as [NuSOAP](http://nusoap.sourceforge.net/).

NuSOAP doesn't require any installation or configuration at the server level. It's just a collection of PHP scripts that you need to include.